# Bash: Ignore empty space at the start of line

Tags: bash

I have just a cosmetic question.

I export some variable at my `.bashrc` as the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/matlab/bin/glnxa64:\
$FASTNET_INSTALL_PATH/lib:$EGRINGERANATOOLS/lib:\
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

but I am used to indent the lines consequent to the start of the command to better viewing, like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/matlab/bin/glnxa64:\
  $FASTNET_INSTALL_PATH/lib:$EGRINGERANATOOLS/lib:\
  $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But if I do that, I will get an error like this:

```
-bash: export: `~/fastnet/install/lib:~/Documents/D3PD/EgRingerAnaTools/lib:': not a valid identifier
```

Is there a way to indent the lines as I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function like this...

```
setpath() {
    oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=":"
    var=$1; shift; eval "$var=\$*; export $var"
    IFS=$oldIFS; unset oldIFS
}

setpath LD_LIBRARY_PATH \
    /usr/local/matlab/bin/glnxa64  \
    "$FASTNET_INSTALL_PATH/lib"    \
    "$EGRINGERANATOOLS/lib"        \
    "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"             ;
```

(I use this function in my ~/.profile, so it was written to be compatible with any shell that reads that file, including sh, ksh, bash, zsh... It would be shorter if written in pure Bash.)

Comment: Now I'm wondering what the hell is `egringerana`, which Google has exactly zero results for.

Comment: Hahhahah, it is a very secret project that I've failed making it secret. Just kidding, it is a project for CERN ATLAS detector for electron and photon identification. EG stands for egamma (electron and photon), RINGER is the project's name, and ANA analysis. If you search for atlas ringer cern you will find something.